# Undefined reference to strlcpy and strlcat

Tags: c

I am using strlcpy and strlcat in place of strncat/cpy; however, whenever I go to compile it
 `GCC -o Project Project.c` it will continuously through me errors saying:

`Undefined reference to strlcpy; Undefined reference to 'strlcat'`
My code:

```
#include <bsd/string.h>
strlcpy(path, ARTICLEPATH, sizeof(ARTICLEPATH));
strlcat(path, ARTICLEPATH, sizeof(path));
```

I have added the library to my file, but it seems to continue to throw me the error:
`#include <bsd/string.h>`

Is there something else I need to do? Or is there an another alternative to using strncpy that utilizes null byte termination?

EDIT: As background, I am on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when I use strlcpy function in c the compilor give me an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547251/when-i-use-strlcpy-function-in-c-the-compilor-give-me-an-error)

Comment: I suspect the `-lbsd` answer on that question is the one you want here.

Comment: @NateEldredge do you mean adding -lbsd to when I compile the program?  Ie: gcc -o -lbsd project project.c ?

Comment: @JamesUkilin: Yes, but put `-lbsd` at the end.  `gcc -o project project.c -lbsd` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc  It certainly can't go after `-o` or you will write your binary to a file named `./-lbsd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is (sort of) explained in the [libbsd man page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libbsd-dev/libbsd.7.en.html), you need to link the `libbsd` library as well as including the header.  So add `-lbsd` to your command line when linking.  For a simple program, you might do

```
gcc -o prog prog.c -lbsd
```

Note that the ordering of options is important here, see [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) If you put `-lbsd` before your source file on the command line, it will probably not work.

The way you asked the question suggests you might have some confusion about the difference between a header and a library, and the roles that each one plays.  You may want to read [What's the difference between a header file and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library/924495#924495)

(This is almost a duplicate of [when I use strlcpy function in c the compilor give me an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547251/when-i-use-strlcpy-function-in-c-the-compilor-give-me-an-error), but that question is more generic and some of the answers aren't applicable to Ubuntu specifically, so I thought a separate answer would be useful.)